# What are the other ways of saying "turn on/off the light"?

Tags: word-usage, expressions

I'm writing about a person who comes into the room twice and both times turns the light on and then off.

I'm wondering if I can avoid repetition with the expressions like

- taps the light switch (off);
- slams the switch on;
- shuts the light (off).

Are those three grammatically correct? Or maybe there are more common ways to say that?

Thank you!

Comment: How about "Switch the light on/off"?

Comment: **slam** is a forceful action. Slam a light switch and you could break it.  Why would you be seeking to avoid repetition when you've gone out of your way to include a repetitive action in your story? Just sayin'

Comment: Extinguish the light ... Kindle the light ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> taps the light switch (off)

and

> slams the switch on

both sound fine to me, although the first might suggest a neutral or tentative mood and the second is more aggressive.

> shut the light off

is rarely used in the context of operating a switch and sounds odd. It's probably more appropriate in a situation where the light is being blocked, for example by closing a door.

In addition to Stu W's suggestion of 'flipping the switch', you could also use:

```
She clicked the light switch on and off again
```

or

```
She flicked the light switch on and off again
```

I use 'light switch' in these examples and not just 'light' because I think 'turn on the light' could refer to a number of ways of switching a lamp on, whereas 'clicking' and 'flicking' (and 'flipping') are more specific to the typical type of plastic wall switch you'd find in modern buildings.

Answer (score 0):

**Flipped the switch.**

*Joe came into the room and flipped the switch, bathing the whole area in warm shades of yellow.*

Comment: Note of interest...a breaker box is  called a _flip-on_ in many parts of Latin America.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, even using different words, a thing can still be repetitive. You could change it more by changing the structure.

For example:

> He peered into the darkness curiously until his hand found the switch again.